# Problem with \maketitle: "there's no line here to end"

Tags: errors, titles

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9 and i'm new to TeX.

Simplified, I have this code:

```
\newcommand{\aone}{Anna}
\newcommand{\atwo}{Bob}
\newcommand{\topic}{Tpoic}
\subject{University \\ Paper}
\title{ \\topic\\ suubtitle}
\author{\aone\and \atwo}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Error:

> There's no line here to end. \end (at `\end{titlepage}`)

Log:

> l.7 `\end{titlepage}`

What can be the problem? I have exclude the titlepage, all seems ok.
I have no idea.

Comment: The first \\ in `\title` is the source of the error.

Comment: Commonly when using `\maketitle` you do not need to enclose it in a `titlepage`-environment. just writing `\maktitle` should do the trick

Comment: If you want to hack your way into a vertically shifted title, you can put a `\vskip1em` at the beginning of your title instead of a newline `\\ `. (Optionally, replace the `1em` part with the amount by which you want the title to be shifted downwards).

Comment: Check out this [page](http://www.golatex.de/wiki/%5Csubject) about titlepage in KOMA script. It's in german but it covers most of your ideas and should also be applicable to other documentclasses (maybe with some minor tweeks).

Comment: please post it as answer, so i can accept. the problem was indeed the "\\". Thanks alot

Comment: @Jubobs Please, add an answer

Comment: The `titlepage` environment is misleadingly useless imho: [What does the titlepage environment do and what are its benefits?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27543)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first `\\` in `\title` is the source of the error. Remove it and your code becomes compilable. You should check [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4692/21891) out for more insight into how `\\` is used.

I understand that you used `\\` in `\title` as an attempt to customise the formatting of the title on the title page. However, it's good practice to do most of the formatting of the title page by either redefining the `\maketitle` command "manually" (the original definition is usually found in the .cls file) or using the [`titling` package](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/layout/titling.pdf).

Final note: as pointed out by @MartinH in his comment, a `titlepage` environment is already used in the definition of the `\maketitle` command ; therefore, there is no need to enclose `\maketitle` inside another `titlepage` environment, as you did in your code.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newcommand{\aone}{Anna}
\newcommand{\atwo}{Bob}
\newcommand{\topic}{Tpoic}
\subject{University \\ Paper}
\title{topic\\ suubtitle}
\author{\aone\and \atwo}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is not directly related to the OPs question, but I had a similar issue while invoking a template file to make the cover page of my document.

If the error is generated on the line that invokes the template file, it probably means that you haven't specified/used all the fields that are specified by the template.

So when you use the file, the undefined parameters would be blank lines and their associated `//` line termination characters will generate a no line here to end error.

Comment: Nice general answer. I'm using the apa6 document style, and had a field blank in the `\twoauthors` environment. You solved my problem.

Comment: @DJHellduck Glad I could help

Comment: This helped me too. I'm using `wiley-article.cls` and I was getting this error upon `\end{frontmatter}` which had nothing to do with the problem. As this solution states, the problem was that I had removed an earlier field (specifically, `\corraddress{...}`), and putting it back in fixed the problem!