# Right align \komavar entries inside a column defined by \setplength

Tags: positioning, koma-script, scrlttr2

I am scratching a custom invoice template based on `scrlttr2` from the [KOMA-Script](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/koma-script3/) and [example code](http://www.komascript.de/files/KOMA-Script-3-Buch-Beispielcode.zip) provided by Markus Kohm (specifically, the files `asymTypB.lco` and `briefwbk.tex` to be found under `KOMA-Script-3/Anhang-E/source`).

In the quest to retouch the design and fit, as well, various information inside the right positioned *Info-Block*, I would like to right-align (**`flushright` or `\raggedleft`? Are they identical?**) the entries `\usekomavar{date}`, `\usekomavar{place}` and `\usekomavar{frombank}`. As almost everything seems to work-out quite nice, instructing `\raggedleft` for the variables in question, they are hooked to the edge of the A4-sized paper.

[image: Partial screenshot picturing the current *Info-Block*].

The code in question that derives this result is sourced from a custom version of the `asymTypB.lco` file:

```
% Main block of Info-Column
\put(0,0){\parbox[t]{\useplength{infocolwidth}}{%
\raggedleft%
    \vspace{\useplength{refvpos}}%
    \vspace{\useplength{refaftervskip}}%
    \usekomavar{date}\\%
    \usekomavar{place}\\[9\baselineskip]%
    %
    \raggedright%
    \usekomavar{fromname}\\[\baselineskip]%
    \ifkomavarempty{company}{}{%
      \\
      \usekomavar{company}%
    }~\\%
    \usekomavar{professiona}\\[\baselineskip]%
    \usekomavar{professionb}\\[2\baselineskip]%
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\[\baselineskip]%
    \usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\[\baselineskip]%
    \ifkomavarempty{fromfax}{}{%
  \\
  \usekomavar*{fromfax}\usekomavar{fromfax}%
    }%
    \usekomavar{fromemail}\\[\baselineskip]%
    %\usekomavar{fromurl}\\%
    \usekomavar{fromlinkedin}\\[2\baselineskip]%
    \usekomavar{fromvatin}\\%
  }%
}%
% Banking information
\put(0,0){\parbox[t]{\useplength{infocolwidth}}{%
    \raggedleft
    \vspace{\useplength{firstfootvpos}}%
    \vspace{-\footskip}%
    \usekomavar{frombank}%
  }%
}%
\end{picture}%
\hspace*{\useplength{infocolwidth}}%
```

What I am after is to get the lengthiest entry in the info-block (i.e. the *LinkedIn* entry currently) and use its distance to the edge of the paper as a margin for *date*, *place* and *frombank* so as to align them in the virtual right border of the info-block.

The `infocolwidth` is defined in the same `.lco` file by `\@setplength{infocolwidth}{.2.5\paperwidth}`.

How can I make this look nice? Besides, although I've read https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4692/8272 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7459/8272, I still can't fix all of the `"There's no line here to end" \opening{text}` errors.

**Update** Files for a (not exactly) Minimal Working Example attached.

custom_AsymTypB.lco

```
% Custom Template for an Inoice (Letter)
% Based on:

% asymTypB.lco
% Copyright 2008 Markus Kohm

% Metadata about this file
\ProvidesFile{asymTypB.lco}%
             [2011/09/20 v0.2 unsupported LCO-file]%

% DIN 676 B
\LoadLetterOption{DINmtext}%

% Place letter body to the left
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}%
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}%

% Again... ?
\AfterCalculatingTypearea{%
  \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}%
  \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}%
}%
\activateareas

% Head
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{0pt}%
\@setplength{firstheadwidth}{\paperwidth}%

% Foot
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{\paperheight}%
\@addtoplength[-]{firstfootvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}%

% Reference
\@addtoplength{refvpos}{-1.5\baselineskip}%

% New variable(s) here!
\newkomavar{company}%
\newkomavar{professiona}%
\newkomavar{professionb}%
\newkomavar[VATin]{fromvatin}%
\newkomavar{fromlinkedin}%

% New variables that concern the client here!
% \newkomavar*[Your VATin]{yourvatin}%

% Set pseudo-length for infocol
\@newplength{infocolwidth}%
\ifdim \textwidth<0.666\paperwidth% How is this supposed to work?
  \@setplength{infocolwidth}{.22222\paperwidth}%
\else
  \@setplength{infocolwidth}{.2.5\paperwidth}%{0.1667\paperwidth}%
\fi


% Set Head first... ?
\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \fontsize{8}{9}\sffamily% Font size(s)
  \hspace*{\fill}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)%
    % Logo?
    \put(0,0){\parbox[t]{\useplength{infocolwidth}}{%
        \vspace{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}%
        \usekomavar{fromlogo}%
      }%
    }%
    % Main block of Info-Column
    \put(0,0){\parbox[t]{\useplength{infocolwidth}}{%
    \flushright%
        \vspace{\useplength{refvpos}}%
        \vspace{\useplength{refaftervskip}}%
        \usekomavar{date}\\%
        \usekomavar{place}\\[9\baselineskip]%
        %
        \raggedright%
        \usekomavar{fromname}\\[\baselineskip]%
        \ifkomavarempty{company}{}{%
          \\
          \usekomavar{company}%
        }\\[\baselineskip]%
        \usekomavar{professiona}\\[\baselineskip]%
        \usekomavar{professionb}\\[2\baselineskip]%
        \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\[\baselineskip]%
        \usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\[\baselineskip]%
        \ifkomavarempty{fromfax}{}{%
      \\
      \usekomavar*{fromfax}\usekomavar{fromfax}%
        }%
        \usekomavar{fromemail}\\[\baselineskip]%
%         \usekomavar{fromurl}\\%
        \usekomavar{fromlinkedin}\\[2\baselineskip]%
        \usekomavar{fromvatin}\\%
      }%
    }%
    % Banking information
    \put(0,0){\parbox[t]{\useplength{infocolwidth}}{%
        \raggedleft
        \vspace{\useplength{firstfootvpos}}%
        \vspace{-\footskip}%
        \usekomavar{frombank}%
      }%
    }%
  \end{picture}%
  \hspace*{\useplength{infocolwidth}}%
}%
\KOMAoption{refline}{nodate}
\setkomavar{nexthead}{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \if@twoside\ifodd\number\value{page}\else
      \@tempswafalse
  \fi\fi
  \if@tempswa
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \hspace*{-\oddsidemargin}\hspace{-1in}%
      \hspace{\paperwidth}%
      \hspace{-\useplength{infocolwidth}}%
      \normalfont\fontsize{7}{8}\sffamily
      \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(0,0){\parbox[t]{\useplength{infocolwidth}}{%
            \vspace*{-\topmargin}\vspace{-1in}%
            \vspace{-\headheight}%
            \vspace{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}%
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
              \usekomavar{fromlogo}\\
              \usekomavar{company}\\
            \end{tabular}%
          }%
        }%
      \end{picture}%
    }%
  \fi
}%
\pagestyle{headings}%
\endinput
```

custom_invoice_template.tex

```
% custom invoice template -- Minimal Working Example
% Based on:

% brieftemplate.tex
% Copyright 2008 Markus Kohm


\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

% \usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc} % Also for ``Greek'' Content
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0cm,bmargin=0cm}

\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}

% No indentation at all!
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[scaled=0.87]{luximono}
% \usepackage[scaled=0.92]{frutigernext}% Does not play nice!

%
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1000000000000001}

% hyperref
\usepackage[%
  pdftitle={PDF-Title},
  pdfauthor={Author},
  pdfsubject={PDF-Subject},
  pdfkeywords={keyword1, keyword2, keyword3},
  linkcolor=magenta,
  urlcolor=marineblue2,
  citecolor=blue,
  pdfstartview={FitH},
  hyperfootnotes=false,
  unicode=true,
  bookmarks=false,
  breaklinks=false,
  pdfborder={0 0 0},
  backref=false,
  colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

% \providecommand{\SetSize}{%
%   \AtBeginDvi{\special{papersize=210mm,210mm}}%
%   \AtBeginDocument{%
%     \ifpdfoutput{%
%       \pdfpagewidth=210mm
%       \pdfpageheight=210mm
%     }{}%
%   }%
% }
% \SetSize


%
\makeatletter

% Martin Vogels Symbols
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{ocr}

% Colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

% define marine blue
\definecolor{marineblue}{rgb}{0.05,0.1,0.4}
\definecolor{marineblue2}{rgb}{0.05,0.1,0.5}

% define lightgray
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{lightgray2}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{lightgray-coursework}{gray}{0.3}

%% Remove preceeding '%' to uncomment an item
\KOMAoptions{%
DIV=last%
,headsepline=true%            separate the header with a line on page >1
%,footsepline=true%             separate the footer with a line on page >1
%pagenumber=botcenter%   position of the page number (see docu)
%,parskip=false%          Use indent instead of skip (more options cf. docu)
% ,fromalign=center%        alignment of the address
,fromrule=aftername%    separate the address with a line?
,fromphone=true%         print sender phone number
,fromfax=false%          print sender fax number
,fromemail=true%           print sender e-mail address
,fromurl=true%               print sender URL
,fromlogo=true%         print a logo (position depends on fromalign)
%,addrfield=false%        print an address field?
,backaddress=false%  print the back address?
,subject=left%,titled% alternative subject layout and position
%,locfield=narrow%      width of the (extra) location field
,foldmarks=false%      print foldmarks?
%,numericaldate=true%  date layout
,refline=wide%             layout of the refline
}

%% Customize Separators
%\setkomavar{placeseparator}{ -- }
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{ $\cdot$ }
%\setkomavar{emailseparator}{ --> }
%\setkomavar{enclseparator}{ > }
%\setkomavar{faxseparator}{ --> }
%\setkomavar{phoneseparator}{ --> }
%\setkomavar{subjectseparator}{ >>> }

%% Customize fonts
%% Use LaTeX's standard font commands
%% Modify with \setkomafont or \addtokomafont
%% (see KOMA documentation)
% \setkomafont{backaddress}{\rmfamily}
%\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{}
% \setkomafont{fromaddress}{\small}
\setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape}
%\setkomafont{pagefoot}{}
%\setkomafont{pagehead}{}
%\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}
%\setkomafont{subject}{}
%\setkomafont{title}{}

% Logo
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[clip,width=3cm,height=3cm,bb = 0 0 200 100, draft, type=eps]{qr_coded_mecard}\\
{\scriptsize{\textcolor{lightgray}{MECARD}\hfill{}}}}

% Name
\setkomavar{fromname}{\noun{First & Last Name}}

% Signature
\setkomavar{signature}{\includegraphics[width=84mm,height=24mm,keepaspectratio,bb = 0 0 200 100, draft, type=eps]{signature}\\
{\small{First Last Name}}}

% Professional Identity
\setkomavar{company}{Company}
\setkomavar{professiona}{Professional Activities A}
\setkomavar{professionb}{Professional Activities B}

% VATin
\setkomavar{fromvatin}{VAT\,in \ocr{ZZ\,000\,000\,000}\\Public Financial Service}
% \setkomavar{yourvatin}{Your \ocr{VAT}}

% Address(es)
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{{\small\Letter~}\\Address Line 1\\Postal Code, City\\Country}
% \setkomavar{fromzipcode}

% Phone
\setkomavar{fromphone}[]{{\large\Mobilefone}\\{\ocr{+00\,9999\,666\,333}}}

% FAX
% \setkomavar{fromfax}[]

% e-Mail
\setkomavar{fromemail}{{\large\Email}\\{\href{mailto:userd-id@domain.name}{user-id\,@\,domain.name}}}

% Web
\setkomavar{fromurl}{{\Info}~\href{web:website.ext}{website.ext}}
\setkomavar{fromlinkedin}{\includegraphics[width=0.25cm,height=0.25cm]{linkedin.png}\\{\href{http://gr.linkedin.com/pub/AccountName}{linkedin.com/pub/AccountName}}}

% Banking
\setkomavar{frombank}{Account holder\\%
\textcolor{blue}{\ocr{First Name, Last Name}}\\%
IBAN\\%
\textcolor{blue}{\ocr{zz0000011111222223333344444}}\\%
SWIFT\,-\,BIC\\%
\textcolor{blue}{\ocr{QWERTYUI}}}%
```

custom_invoice_mwe.tex

```
%% custom invoice template -- Minimal Working Example
%% Based on:

% briefwbk.tex
% Copyright 2008 Markus Kohm

\documentclass[%
  english,
  custom_asymTypB,
  DIV=8,
  fontsize=11pt]{scrlttr2}

% What, Where, When?
\setkomavar{subject}{Quotation for... \textbf{yyy}}

% \setkomavar{toname}
% \setkomavar{toaddress}

% \setkomavar{customer}
% \setkomavar{refname}
% \setkomavar{refvalue}

% \setkomavar{invoice}


\setkomavar{myref}{Project: yyy}

% Place, Location
% \setkomavar{placeseparator}
\setkomavar{place}{Place}
% \setkomavar{location}{Location}

% Date
\setkomavar{date}{\today}

% Structure and Basic Information
\input{custom_invoice_template.tex}

\begin{document}

  \begin{letter}{Mr. xxx xxx\\
  Institution\\
  Description\\
  Address Line 1\\
  Address Line 2\\
  Country}

  \opening{Dear xxx,}

  \begin{flushleft}
  herewith I am sending you a quotation...
  \end{flushleft}

  \closing{Sincerely yours,}

  \encl{Enclosures}
  \cc{}

  \end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal working example please?

Comment: Sure! I just though it'll be something obvious to the experienced eye.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to the initial question. However, kind of a working solution, by hardcoding distances (which is, of course, not what is asked for).

Corrections and hints to improve the outlook more than welcome. For example, how to correctly place the signature at the footer's location.

**custom_AsymTypB.lco**

```
% Custom Template for an Invoice (Letter)
% Based on:

% asymTypB.lco
% Copyright 2008 Markus Kohm

% Metadata about this file
\ProvidesFile{asymTypB.lco}%
             [2011/09/20 v0.2 unsupported LCO-file]%

% DIN 676 B
\LoadLetterOption{DINmtext}%

% Place letter body to the left
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}%
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-2.54cm}%

% Again... ?
\AfterCalculatingTypearea{%
  \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}%
  \addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-2.54cm}%
}%
\activateareas

% Head
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{0pt}%
\@setplength{firstheadwidth}{\paperwidth}%

% Foot
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{\paperheight}%
\@addtoplength[-]{firstfootvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}%

% Reference
\@addtoplength{refvpos}{-1.5\baselineskip}%

% New variable(s) here!
\newkomavar{company}%
\newkomavar{professiona}%
\newkomavar{professionb}%
\newkomavar{fromvatin}%
\newkomavar{fromlinkedin}%

% New variables that concern the client here!
\newkomavar*[Your VAT\,in]{yourvatin}%

% Set pseudo-length for infocol
\@newplength{infocolwidth}%
\ifdim \textwidth<0.666\paperwidth% How is this supposed to work?
  \@setplength{infocolwidth}{.2\paperwidth}%
\else
  \@setplength{infocolwidth}{.21\paperwidth}%{0.1667\paperwidth}%
\fi


% Set Head first... ?
\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \fontsize{9}{10}\sffamily% Font size(s)
  \hspace*{\fill}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)%
    % Logo?
    \put(0,0){\parbox[t]{\useplength{infocolwidth}}{%
        \vspace{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}%
        \usekomavar{fromlogo}%
      }%
    }%
    % Date only
      \put(-224,0){\parbox[t]{2.45\useplength{infocolwidth}}{%
        \flushright
        \vspace{\useplength{refvpos}}%
        \vspace{\useplength{refaftervskip}}%
        \usekomavar{place}\\%
        \usekomavar{date}%
      }
      }
    % Main block of Info-Column
      \put(0,0){\parbox[t]{\useplength{infocolwidth}}{%
        \raggedright%
        \vspace{\useplength{refvpos}}%
        \vspace{\useplength{refaftervskip}}
        \vspace{8\baselineskip}%
        \usekomavar{fromname}\\[\baselineskip]%
        \ifkomavarempty{company}{}{%
          \\
          \usekomavar{company}\\%
        }%
        \usekomavar{professiona}\\[\baselineskip]%
        \usekomavar{professionb}\\[\baselineskip]%
        \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\[\baselineskip]%
        \usekomavar*{fromphone}\usekomavar{fromphone}\\[\baselineskip]%
        \ifkomavarempty{fromfax}{}{%
      \\
      \usekomavar*{fromfax}\usekomavar{fromfax}%
        }%
        \usekomavar{fromemail}\\[\baselineskip]%
        %\usekomavar{fromurl}\\%
        \usekomavar{fromlinkedin}\\[\baselineskip]%
        \usekomavar[\textbf{\textcolor{lightgray06}{VAT\,in}}\\]{fromvatin}%
      }%
    }%
    % Banking information
    \put(-200,0){\parbox[t]{2.45\useplength{infocolwidth}}{%
        \flushright
        \vspace{\useplength{firstfootvpos}}%
        \vspace{-\footskip}%
        \usekomavar{frombank}%
      }%
    }%
  \end{picture}%
  \hspace*{\useplength{infocolwidth}}%
}%
\KOMAoption{refline}{nodate}
\setkomavar{nexthead}{%
  \@tempswatrue
  \if@twoside\ifodd\number\value{page}\else
      \@tempswafalse
  \fi\fi
  \if@tempswa
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \hspace*{-\oddsidemargin}\hspace{-1in}%
      \hspace{\paperwidth}%
      \hspace{-\useplength{infocolwidth}}%
      \normalfont\fontsize{7}{8}\sffamily
      \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(0,0){\parbox[t]{\useplength{infocolwidth}}{%
            \vspace*{-\topmargin}\vspace{-1in}%
            \vspace{-\headheight}%
            \vspace{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}%
            \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
              \usekomavar{fromlogo}\\
              \usekomavar{company}\\
            \end{tabular}%
          }%
        }%
      \end{picture}%
    }%
  \fi
}%
\pagestyle{headings}%
\endinput
```

**custom_invoice_template.tex**

```
% custom invoice template -- Minimal Working Example
% Based on:

% brieftemplate.tex
% Copyright 2008 Markus Kohm


\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

% \usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc} % Also for ``Greek'' Content?
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=0cm,bmargin=0cm}

\setlength{\parskip}{\smallskipamount}

% No indentation at all!
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


% Colors

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% define marine blue
\definecolor{marineblue}{rgb}{0.05,0.1,0.4}
\definecolor{marineblue2}{rgb}{0.05,0.1,0.5}

% define lightgray
\definecolor{lightgray08}{gray}{0.8}
\definecolor{lightgray06}{gray}{0.6}
\definecolor{lightgray04}{gray}{0.4}
\definecolor{lightgray02}{gray}{0.2}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[scaled=0.87]{luximono}
% \usepackage[scaled=0.92]{frutigernext}% Does not play nice!

%
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.15}

% hyperref
\usepackage[%
  pdftitle={PDF-Title},
  pdfauthor={Author},
  pdfsubject={PDF-Subject},
  pdfkeywords={keyword1, keyword2, keyword3},
  linkcolor=magenta,
  urlcolor=marineblue2,
  citecolor=blue,
  pdfstartview={FitH},
  hyperfootnotes=false,
  unicode=true,
  bookmarks=false,
  breaklinks=false,
  pdfborder={0 0 0},
  backref=false,
  colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

% \providecommand{\SetSize}{%
%   \AtBeginDvi{\special{papersize=210mm,210mm}}%
%   \AtBeginDocument{%
%     \ifpdfoutput{%
%       \pdfpagewidth=210mm
%       \pdfpageheight=210mm
%     }{}%
%   }%
% }
% \SetSize


%
\makeatletter

% Martin Vogels Symbols
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{ocr}

%% Remove preceeding '%' to uncomment an item
\KOMAoptions{%
DIV=last%
,headsepline=true%  separate the header with a line on page >1
%,footsepline=true% separate the footer with a line on page >1
%pagenumber=botcenter%  position of the page number (see docu)
,parskip=full-% Use indent instead of skip (more options cf. docu)
%,fromalign=center% alignment of the address
,fromrule=aftername%    separate the address with a line?
,fromphone=true%    print sender phone number
,fromfax=false%     print sender fax number
,fromemail=true%    print sender e-mail address
,fromurl=true%      print sender URL
,fromlogo=true%     print a logo (position depends on fromalign)
%,addrfield=false%  print an address field?
% ,backaddress=false%   print the back address?
,subject=centered%,titled%  alternative subject layout and position
%,locfield=narrow%  width of the (extra) location field
,foldmarks=true%    print foldmarks?
% ,numericaldate=true%  date layout
,refline=narrow%    layout of the refline
}

%% Customize Separators

\setkomavar{placeseparator}{~}%\setkomavar{placeseparator}{ -- }
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{ $\cdot$ }
%\setkomavar{emailseparator}{ --> }
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{ > }
%\setkomavar{faxseparator}{ --> }
%\setkomavar{phoneseparator}{ --> }
%\setkomavar{subjectseparator}{ >>> }

%% Customize fonts
%% Use LaTeX's standard font commands
%% Modify with \setkomafont or \addtokomafont
%% (see KOMA documentation)
% \setkomafont{backaddress}{\rmfamily}
%\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{}
% \setkomafont{fromaddress}{\small}
\setkomafont{fromname}{\scshape}
%\setkomafont{pagefoot}{}
%\setkomafont{pagehead}{}
%\setkomafont{pagenumber}{}
%\setkomafont{title}{}
\addtokomafont{title}{\color{lightgray04}}
%\setkomafont{subject}{}
\addtokomafont{subject}{\color{lightgray06}}

\addtokomafont{foldmark}{\color{lightgray08}}

% Place, Location

% \setkomavar{placeseparator
\setkomavar{place}{\textcolor{lightgray04}{SomePlace, SomeCountry}}
% \setkomavar{location}


% Logo
\setkomavar{fromlogo}{\includegraphics[clip,width=3cm,height=3cm,bb = 0 0 200 100, draft, type=eps]{qr_coded_mecard}\\
{\scriptsize{\textcolor{lightgray}{MECARD}\hfill{}}}}

% Name

\setkomavar{fromname}{\textcolor{lightgray04}{\textsc{FirstName \textbf{LastName}}, Title}}


% Signature
\setkomavar{signature}{\includegraphics[width=84mm,height=24mm,keepaspectratio,bb = 0 0 200 100, draft, type=eps]{signature}\\
{\small{Fisrt & Last Name}}}


% Professional Identity / Company

\setkomavar{company}{\textcolor{lightgray04}{Company}}


% Professional Identities

\setkomavar{professiona}{\textcolor{lightgray06}{Profession A}}
\setkomavar{professionb}{\textcolor{lightgray04}{Profession B}\\%
  \textcolor{lightgray06}{Profession B Related Info}}


% VATin

\setkomavar{fromvatin}{\textcolor{lightgray04}{\ocr{XX\,111\,222\,333}\\Financial Service\\SomePlace, SomeCountry}}


% Address(es)

\setkomavar{fromaddress}{{\large\textcolor{lightgray06}{\Letter}}~\\{\color{lightgray04}{Street Nr.\\Postal\,Code City\\Country}}}
\setkomavar{fromzipcode}{Postal\,Code}
\setkomavar{backaddress}{Name\\Street Nr.\\Postal\,Code City\\Country}


% Phone

\setkomavar{fromphone}[]{{\large\textcolor{lightgray06}{\Mobilefone}}\\{\textcolor{lightgray04}{\ocr{+00\,1122\,333\,444}}}}


% FAX
% \setkomavar{fromfax}[]

% e-Mail

\setkomavar{fromemail}{{\large\textcolor{lightgray04}{\Email}}\\{\href{mailto:userid@domain.name}{userid\,@\,domain.name}}}


% Web

\setkomavar{fromurl}{{\Info}~\href{web:websitename}{websitename}}
\setkomavar{fromlinkedin}{\includegraphics[width=0.25cm,height=0.25cm]{linkedin.png}\\{\href{http://xx.linkedin.com/pub/account-name}{linkedin.com/pub/account-name}}}


% Banking

\setkomavar{frombank}{\color{lightgray06}{Account holder}\\%
\textcolor{lightgray04}{\ocr{NAME LASTNAME}}\\[\smallskip]%
IBAN\\%
\textcolor{lightgray04}{\ocr{XX0123456789012345678901234}}\\[\smallskip]%
SWIFT\,-\,BIC\\%
\textcolor{lightgray04}{\ocr{QQQQQQQQ}}}%
```

**custom_invoice_mwe.tex**

```
%% custom invoice template -- Minimal Working Example
%% Based on:

% briefwbk.tex
% Copyright 2008 Markus Kohm

\documentclass[%
  english,
  custom_asymTypB,
  DIV=8,
  fontsize=11pt]{scrlttr2}

% Structure and Basic Information
\input{custom_invoice_template.tex}


% What, Where, When?
\setkomavar{title}{Quotation - Invoice}
\setkomavar{subject}{Quotation for... \textbf{yyy}}

% \setkomavar{toname}
% \setkomavar{toaddress}

% \setkomavar{customer}
% \setkomavar{refname}
% \setkomavar{refvalue}

% \setkomavar{invoice}

\setkomavar{myref}{Project: yyy}


% Place, Location
\setkomavar{place}{Place}
% \setkomavar{placeseparator}
% \setkomavar{location}{Location}


% Date
\setkomavar{date}{\today}


\begin{document}

  \begin{letter}{Mr. xxx xxx\\
  Institution\\
  Description\\
  Address Line 1\\
  Address Line 2\\
  Country}

  \opening{Dear xxx,}

  \begin{flushleft}
  herewith I am sending you a quotation...
  \end{flushleft}


  \closing{Sincerely yours,}

  \encl{Enclosures}
  \cc{}

  \end{letter}

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image: Screenshot of the Custom Invoice (MWE) Template]