# Greek description for custom variables (\newkomavar*) in lco-file

Tags: pdftex, koma-script, greek, scrlttr2

Based on the templates/files `asymTypB.lco`, `brieftemplate.tex`, `briefwbk.tex` found at http://www.komascript.de/files/KOMA-Script-3-Buch-Beispielcode.zip, I derived a modified template for an invoice (initially as posted at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152558/8272).

Attempting to translate this into Greek (available at https://github.com/NikosAlexandris/invoice_el), I've added the following instructions, as per KOMA's guide recommendations:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%

\providecaptionname{greek}{\datename}{Ημερομηνία}%
\providecaptionname{greek}\subjectname{Θέμα}%

\providecaptionname{greek}\headtoname{Προς}%

\providecaptionname{greek}{\customername}{Πελάτης (Κωδικός, Αριθμός)}%
\providecaptionname{greek}\yourmailname{Εγγραφή Πελάτη}%
\providecaptionname{greek}{\yourrefname}{Διακριτικός τίτλος έργου}%

\providecaptionname{greek}\headfromname{Από}%
\providecaptionname{greek}\emailname{η-Ταχυδρομείο}%
\providecaptionname{greek}\wwwname{Url}%
\providecaptionname{greek}\phonename{Τηλέφωνο}%
\providecaptionname{greek}\faxname{Τηλεομοιότυπο}%

\providecaptionname{greek}{\myrefname}{Εσωτερική εγγραφή}%
\providecaptionname{greek}{\invoicename}{Τιμολόγιο No.}%
\providecaptionname{greek}{\bankname}{Τραπεζικός Λογαριασμός}%

\providecaptionname{greek}\ccname{cc}%
\providecaptionname{greek}\enclname{Επισυναπτόμενα}%

\providecaptionname{greek}\pagename{Σελίδα}%
}
```

In addition, I added new variables in the respective `.lco` file as explaiend in [(this) KOMA's script guide (english version, page 371)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf), a new variable accepts a pre-defined description, i.e.: `newkomavar*[description ]{name }`.  For example,

```
% New variable(s) here!
\newkomavar{company}%
\newkomavar{professiona}%
\newkomavar{professionb}%
\newkomavar{fromvatin}%
\newkomavar{fromlinkedin}%
```

So far is all fine.  However, adding a greek description for a custom variable, won't work as expected. To exemplify, the following

```
\newkomavar*[ΑΦΜ Πελάτη]{yourvatin}%
```

appears in the compiled pdf (PDFLaTeX) as `ὐἇὐᾔὐῂ ὐήὐᾡὐὢὐῇὓᾲὐᾣ`.  **How should a greek description for custom koma variables be realised (inside PDFLaTeX) from inside an .lco file?**

Comment: Kind of a minimal working example available at https://github.com/NikosAlexandris/invoice_el/blob/master/custom_invoice_mwe_el.tex

Comment: I think `refname` and `refvalue` must also be declared with `\newkomavar`. I get "Class scrlttr2 Error: KOMA-Script variable not defined."

Comment: Thanks for the comment. **scrguien** says: _When you define a variable for the reference fields line you should always give it a description,_ which is the case here (`\newkomavar*[ΑΦΜ Πελάτη]{yourvatin}%`). If you mean the two lines where `refname` and `refvalue` are wrongly attempted to be set, they were leftovers from a trial and error run. I removed them now. I do not see, however, how they were related with the false appearance of the Greek description of the custom variable `yourvatin`. Could you provide an example?

Comment: The leftover lines were probably not related to the bad output you are seeing. However, it's important that a MWE can be compiled. Even after the update, I cannot compile the example: pdflatex prints "! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end" on line 62 which has the `\opening` command. I don't know if the problem is with the document or my TeX installation. I'm using TeX Live 2014 pretest.

Comment: @mvkorpel Thanks for your attention. I don't know how to deal with this. Looking at it.  Anyhow, I get a PDF, despite errors and my main problem is the "Greek" description of the custom variable. I will try to fix all errors in time. Ideas on where to look are, of course, welcome.

Comment: I was able to compile the example without errors by applying the following changes: 1. In `custom_invoice_asymTypB_el.lco`, I moved `\raggedright` to be the last command inside the `\parbox` titled "Main block of Info-Column". I don't know why this helps. 2. In `custom_invoice_template_el.tex`, I replaced `\smallskip` with `\smallskipamount`: a length is required. 3. Also in the template file, I commented out `\setkomavar` lines where `\includegraphics` points to a non-existent file. Bonus: I moved `\makeatletter` down to just before `\@setplength` and used `\makeatother` to reset the change.

Comment: @mvkorpel Do you have a github account?  Or, could you send me the file and I'll apply the diff myself. That's brilliant :-)

Comment: I made a pull request on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example files seem to use UTF-8 encoding. The sequence of UTF-8 hex codes from the individual letters of "ΑΦΜΠελάτη" is `ce91 cea6 ce9c cea0 ceb5 cebb ceac cf84 ceb7` (note: space was removed).

I am not familiar with the intricate details of Greek font encodings in LaTeX, but the table of the LGR encoding in the [LaTeX font encodings](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf) manual maps the bytes of the UTF-8 sequence (`ce`, `91`, `ce`, `a6`, ...) to the wrong output you are seeing.

### A new example

As I am not able to compile your example document, I must demonstrate the issue and proposed solutions with minimal examples of my own.

First, the problem occurs when no inputenc has been defined:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
ΑΦΜ Πελάτη
\end{document}
```

[image: picture with wrong character sequence]

The problem can be solved by:

A. defining a suitable input encoding

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
ΑΦΜ Πελάτη
\end{document}
```

or

B. using character codes found in the LGR table. The mapping from "ΑΦΜΠελάτη" to decimal codes is 65, 70, 77, 80, 101, 108, 136, 116, 104.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\char65\char70\char77{} \char80\char101\char108\char136\char116\char104
\end{document}
```

Both A and B give the same result:

[image: picture with correct character sequence]

### Applying this to the original example

I guess the character code solution (B) would work as such. For the input encoding solution to work, I think you would need to move the `\inputenc` declaration to an earlier location in your document, before any Greek text. Note that in your example the `.lco` template containing `\newkomavar*[ΑΦΜ Πελάτη]{yourvatin}` is included straight from `\documentclass`, before the declaration of an `\inputenc`.

Comment: Your answer (especially the very last paragrah), lead me to an answer :-). I modified the .lco file so as to be, regarding the custom variable in question, `\newkomavar*[\yourvatinname]{yourvatin}` and `\providecaptionname{english}\yourvatinname{Customer's VATin}`. It's a step forward.

Comment: Appears that I wasn't persistent enough when trying to compile your example document. The current version requires 18 presses of <return> to pdflatex, but finally a pdf is produced. The previous version only requires 10 <return>s. Interesting. Every error happens on the `\opening` line.

Comment: I will get back on this once I have some more free time. I certainly want to have a clean template, after eliminating all errors, one by one. Your invaluable time is helping me getting there.