# Strange "no line here to end" error

Tags: errors

Unfortunately I didn't find any helpful question that already exists, so I need to open a new one on my problem.

I have two main documents I use. One is the `main.tex` with the entire thesis, and one is the `SingleChapter.tex` where I use single chapters for faster PDF creation. The files look pretty similar with both of them having some (working) header and settings part, and lots of included `chapter.tex` files.

When using the `SingleChapter` file everything works fine, but when using the `main.tex` I get the "no line here to end" error on

```
\chapter{Chaptername}
\include{./Chapter/Chaptername.tex}
```

Also, with commenting these two lines out the same error occurs in the same lines.

I don't get it.

Can you please help me?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Put the chapter command inside the include file, or don't use include but \input.

Comment: it will not generate the error that you state but almost always the `\chapter` heading should be inside the included file otherwise you get a forced page break after the heading. The error is telling you of a bad use of `\\ ` but unless you show your code it is not possible to say what you have done wrong.

Comment: also _never_ use the  explicit `.tex` extension with `include` just use `\include{./Chapter/Chaptername}`

Comment: Hi Guys,Thanks for the quick response. 
I will check that, and swap the include by inputs and throw away the .tex's and report if the error still occurs.

Comment: It's really better to put the `\chapter` line *in* the included file; leave it in the main file but comment it out -- that will allow you to take advantage of `\includeonly`.  That said, the error is probably being reported for the line just previous to the `\chapter` line -- and that means it's quite possibly in another file.

Comment: Hi, now I'm using the \input{Chapter} without the explicit .tex extension. But still I get the errors while producing the .pdf file.
The error now also occurs on a line, that is commented out , with several li nes above and below also being commented out.

Comment: Some errors in TeX are only reported a few lines after the initial cause of the error. Several `\include`d subfiles can make it even harder to find the culprit because the line number may not refer to the main file, but rather to an included file. It would be great if you could try to isolate the source of the error. A good way to do that is the binary search method described in https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 and https://www.codelord.net/2012/04/10/using-binary-search-for-debugging/. If you can show us code that reproduces the error you are much more likely to get a good answer

Comment: ... The message `no line here to end` often occurs when people use ```\\``` extensively in the text to end lines or paragraphs. In normal text one should usually not have to use ```\\```. Paragraphs are ended with a blank line or `\par`. ```\\``` should be used almost exclusively in tables and `tabular`/`array`-like structures and in math mode. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4690/35864