# there is no line to end

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, line-breaking, line, block

I've "there is no line to end" prolem at my 8th line.

How to correct this.

```
\begin{document}
\title{\textbf{Aléatoire} \\\\\\\\
Introduction à la théorie \\\\
et au calcul des probabilités}

\author{Toto}

\date{ }
\maketitle
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Tables des matières}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapitre}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\tableofcontents
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\chapter{Introduction}
```

Comment: remove all the \\

Comment: As David says, never use ``\\`` in your text they are always (well almost) wrong.

Comment: possible duplicates https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66495/best-choice-between-using-or-leaving-space-after-each-paragraph-to-end-the-pa and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4690/36296

Comment: @Fractal Please stop posting new questions as solutions. In your previous question, 3 of your non-answers already had to be deleted and now you are doing it again. This causes a lot of work. People have to flag the posts, reviewers have to take a look at them ...

Answer (score 3):

In word processors, vertical space between lines is always a multiple of the common baseline distance, because you can just hit return a few times until you're satisfied by the result.

Well, *advanced* word processors might have a way to specify the desired distance, but I'm not aware of such a feature (perhaps because I'm no word processor user).

In LaTeX you can specify *precisely* what amount of space you want. And `\\ \\` will invariably lead to errors (unless you're in some environment where you can or must end lines manually, such as `flushleft` or `tabular`). But, as a general rule, `\\ \\` should be avoided even there.

The command `\\` has an optional argument: with

```
\\[4ex]
```

you specify that the line should end and that a vertical space of 4 ex units is desired. You can use any legal unit: `in`, `cm`, `mm`, and so on. But `ex` is good in this context, because its value depends on the current font.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % mandatory for French
\usepackage[french]{babel} % mandatory for French

\begin{document}

\title{\textbf{Aléatoire} \\[8ex]
Introduction à la théorie \\[2ex]
et au calcul des probabilités}

\author{Toto}

\date{}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

#### Title page

[image]

#### TOC

[image]

#### Chapter page

[image]

#### Notes

If you write in French, you have to tell LaTeX, not just redefine `\contentsname` or `\chaptername`. You don't want to hyphenate French according to American English rules, I believe.

With the `oneside` option, there is no need to do the awful `\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage`.